# Can you add knockoutjs style binding specifying property+value together?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a question regarding the style binding. Is it possible to generate the whole style binding text? So the property and value parts together?
For example:

```
    function ViewModel() {
    this.fontSize = ko.observable(12);

    this.fontSizeCSS = ko.computed(function() {
        return "font-size: " + " " + this.fontSize() + "px";
    }, this);

}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The the simple way is to do like this:

```
<div data-bind="style: { fontSize: fontSize()  + 'px'}">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do it a way like this( I tried, it did not work):

```
<div data-bind="style: { fontSizeCSS() }">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

If yes, how? If not, why not?
One can do a text binding to a html style element, but I was wondering if you can do it somewhat similar, what I am proposing?
Thanks!

Comment: you shouldn't have () in your binding on the last example.

Comment: Leaving out the () won't solve the issue.

Comment: that's correct, but having incorrect code to begin with doesn't help things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main parameter of the [`style` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html#parameters) is not a `string`, but

> You should pass a **JavaScript object** in which the property names correspond to style names, and the values correspond to the style values you wish to apply.

So your `fontSizeCSS` computed should return an object and not a string, and it will work fine:

```
this.fontSizeCSS = ko.computed(function() {
        return {"fontSize": this.fontSize() + "px"};
}, this);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92KJb/).

Comment: Thanks! It works this way, the only issue is that I have to put fontSize instead of font-size. Could you correct that in your answer?

Comment: @Zsombi which browser are you using? Because it is working fine in my demo both in IE10 and the latest Chrome...

Comment: that's 'cause of this http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html

Comment: Thanks! By the way: Firefox 22.0